# Difficult to show a marker on my current position on the map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

Following different tutorial i added a map view in my controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

}
```

and also this extension

```
extension CourseClass2:  CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {

        guard currentLocation == nil else {
            return
        }

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self 
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        didReceiveUserLocation(userLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
        errorGettingCurrentLocation(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        } else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
            errorGettingCurrentLocation("Location access denied")
        }
    }

    func errorGettingCurrentLocation(_ errorMessage:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

now how can i show in my mapView, my position with a marker on it? I'm getting confusing about it because i have an extension unlike the tutorials i found where the code is all in the class.

Comment: do you know that you can check "User Location" in the view inspector and it will show automatically?

Comment: i want to show in my map when i run the application my current position with a marker on it